# ExecuteNonQuery() breaks the loop and doesn't insert data in SQL database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, executenonquery

Here's the code which tries to enter the data stored in the arrays. The arrays contain data as well as there are empty cells which need not be added into the database. The issue is the code is not throwing any exception or error but it isn't inserting any data in the database too! Please help... Thanks in advance

```
public void saveDb(string[,] timeTableId,string[,] start_time,string[,] end_time,string[,] subject_id,string[,] day,string[,] faculty_id)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AIS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            if (subject_id[i, j].Length != 0 && subject_id[i, j] != null)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TIMETABLE VALUES('" + subject_id[i, j] + "','" + day[i, j] + "','" + start_time[i, j] + "','" + end_time[i, j] + "','" + subject_id[i, j] + "','" + faculty_id[i, j] + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            { 
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @marc_s can you please elaborate?

Comment: Read the link he had in his comment, it explains.

Comment: What if I tried to create a subject named: `');DROP Table Timetable;`?

Comment: Or even just what if any of these fields actually has a single quote as a valid piece of data in it? Apostrophes are not that unusual.

Comment: If it "breaks the loop" then it probably IS throwing an exception. I don't see a try/catch here, so I don't know where it might end up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm elaborating....

1. use **parametrized** queries - first to avoid SQL injection, the #1 vulnerability out there on the internet, second to avoid issues with *how many single or double quotes do I need for this string or date?* and stuff like that - gone if you use properly typed parameters, and third to improve performance - define your parameter **once**, re-use them multiple times (and SQL Server will also create one SQL statement with an execution plan and reuse that!)
2. use **`using(....) { .... }` blocks for all disposable classes - especially `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` - to ensure proper and immediate disposal of unneeded objects.
3. *always* explicitly define the list of columns of a table you're inserting into - don't just rely on the current table structure and order of columns - **explicitly say** what you're doing!

All in all, your method should really look something like this:

```
public void saveDb(string[,] timeTableId,string[,] start_time,string[,] end_time,string[,] subject_id,string[,] day,string[,] faculty_id)
{
    // define connection string - typically should come from a .config file
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AIS;Integrated Security=True";

    // define the SQL query - with *parameters* - and also: explicitly NAME the columns in your target table!
    // also: did you really want to insert the subject_id twice?
    string insertQry = "INSERT INTO dbo.TIMETABLE (col1, col2, col3, ....) " + 
                       " VALUES(@subject_id, @day, @start_time, @end_time, @subject_id, @faculty_id)";

    // set up your connection and command    
    // you didn't tell us what datatypes those are - maybe you need to adapt those to your situation!
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry, con))
    {
        // define your parameters once, before the loop
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@start_time", SqlDbType.Time);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@end_time", SqlDbType.Time);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@faculty_id", SqlDbType.Int);

        con.Open();

        // now start the for loops, and set the parameter values        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                // not sure what these checks should be - left them "as is"
                if (subject_id[i, j].Length != 0 && subject_id[i, j] != null)
                {
                     // set the parameter values
                     cmd.Parameters["@subject_id"].Value = subject_id[i, j];
                     cmd.Parameters["@day"].Value = day[i, j];
                     cmd.Parameters["@start_time"].Value = start_time[i, j];
                     cmd.Parameters["@end_time"].Value = end_time[i, j];
                     cmd.Parameters["@faculty_id"].Value = faculty_id[i, j];

                     // execute query to insert data                     
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }    
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the SQL statement using SQL Profiler, and then, run the query on SQL Management Studio to discover if there's any error on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Use `parameterized` Query and use `Try catch` block to get the `exception` if Any

```
public void saveDb(string[,] timeTableId,string[,] start_time,string[,] end_time,string[,] subject_id,string[,] day,string[,] faculty_id)
{
 SqlConnection con;
  SqlCommand cmd;
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AIS;Integrated Security=True");
try
{
   if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          con.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            if (subject_id[i, j].Length != 0 && subject_id[i, j] != null)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [TIMETABLE](col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) VALUES(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6)", con);

cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col1",subject_id[i, j]);
   // convert type here depend upon the col type
    // cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col1",Convert.ToString(subject_id[i, j]));
   //Or  cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col1",Convert.ToDouble(subject_id[i, j]));
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col2",day[i, j]);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col3",start_time[i, j]);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col4",end_time[i, j]);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col5",subject_id[i, j]);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@col6",faculty_id[i, j]);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
Catch(Exception e1)
{
  throw new System.ArgumentException(e1.Messege, "Error");
}
Finally
{
   if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Catch/Throw makes me sad. So does AddWithValue(), which can lead to big performance issues.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank you, and  what do you suggest instead of  `AddWithValue()` ??

Comment: `AddWithValue("@param", value)` would become: `Add("@param", SqlDbType.SomeType).Value = value` or `Add("@param", SqlDbType.SomeType, lengthvariable).Value = value`

Comment: @user3540365 hello when I tried as the way you said I got the following exception: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Monday' to data type int. I don't know why is it trying to convert it into int and if so, why isn't it causing any problems while inserting from the first array? 'Monday' is from the day[i,j] array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2895532 yes, that's it, everyone asking..
now, you need to  do the proper conversion as per your requirement.

if `day[i,j] ` is `Monday` then you can't  insert it to `col2 int` colum.

Comment: yes I got the problem, it actually lied in the database which was designed by someone else and he accidently (or purposely, who knows) assigned the day field as "int". Problem rectified and solved. Thanks a ton to @user3540365 and all others too!!